# Font not showing in Xcode Attribute Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode ver 13.2.1 and

Hi, I have downloaded Poppins font from fonts.google.com and the problem is it's not showing in the font family dropdown(refer to the attached picture). I have declared it in my Info.plist, Project Target and still the problem occurs [image: Info.plist]

[image: Project>Target>Build Phase>Copy Bundle Resources]
[image: Font Directory]
[image: Attribute Inspector][image: font book]

Comment: have you fixed the issue?

Comment: Creating a new account on my macbook solved the issue. Same issue happened on 2 different macbook(macbook pro 2017 using macos 11 and m2 using macos 13). Both issue has been resolved by creating new user account.

Comment: thanks, will try this.
if you like to an answer to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/74470725/6038161

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The storyboard editor knows nothing of any custom fonts you may have installed for the app.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for font book, what am I missing?